# What are alternatives to Universal Logout in OAuth?

Tags: oauth, architecture, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

OAuth does not support the concept of a 'Universal Logout'. Logging out of one application does not log you out of another, as that would not be the desired behavior.

For example, if a Facebook user were to log out of Facebook, it should not log them out of Spotify (if they were using Facebook OAuth).

I have been hired to create a service that acts as a sub-application to transparently embed itself in the workflow of an older monolithic web application. For example, there is a link to the sub-application from the monolith, and clicking that link transparently moves you into the sub application. The sub-application also links back to the monolith, which transparently leads back. The user is able to weave back and forth between the monolith and the sub-application.

The sub-application currently uses OAuth 2.0 to authenticate through the monolith. From the user's perspective, this is mostly a transparent exchange.

To the user, the two application workflows should weave together as one. Given this, the concept of a 'Universal Logout' is desirable. What appears to be a single application to the user should not have some of the pages logged out and other pages logged in.

I currently have a 'Universal Logout' implemented, but I have a feeling that since this is not a part of OAuth, maybe it means this problem should be tackled in a different way.

Given this scenario, is there an alternative to implementing 'Universal Logout' in OAuth? Should OAuth even be used? If not, what should be done? How could this be better architectured?

Comment: This post – detailing Stack Exchange's "single/global sign-in" – might be of relevance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64274/130770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 itself is not a protocol that logs on users to applications (http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/); some (like Facebook) have built a custom extension of OAuth 2.0 to do that; those providers would have to start supporting a custom Single Logout mechanism as well in order to address the problem you mentioned.

There is however a standardized extension of OAuth 2.0 that logs on users to applications called OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html). That has an extension called Session Management (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) that allows for the functionality that you describe in a standardized way.